# Eclipse 4.2 Desktop MVC JavaFX 2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx-2

I am now migrating to JavaFX on my Desktop development using Eclipse 4.2 [Juno]. JavaFX is still young and most of its documentation are still using Netbeans IDE, are there documentation for Eclipse IDE [maybe from Helios to present]? But this is not my real question.

Model-View-Controller can ease development in both Desktop and Web platforms. Furthermore, in Desktop development, we could call a `View` in the `Controller` by instantiating it (in my approach of MVC). **My question, if I am to migrate to JavaFX, would I still follow the same routine of creating Forms as I did in Swing?** If there is a greate change in my routine, kindly incidate how would it be done then. Usually in my approach of MVC, the `View` holds the layout and methods on how the `Model(s)` is to be rendered in it. For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class SampleView extends JFrame  {
   // javax.swing.* Components, i.e. JTextField, JPanel, etc.
   public SampleView() {
      initializeLayout();      
   }
   private void initializeLayout() {
      // How the components are to be placed using `GroupLayout`
   }
   // others methods for rendering Model(s) in this view
   // EventHandling of components are placed the Controller of this View.
}
```

Comment: *"I've recently read"* Just because you see something on a web page, does not mean it is true.  I made a comment on that answer asking for the source of that 'information' - since I find it hard to believe.

Comment: JavaFX is not going to deprecate Swing. Both will continue to co-exist for many years to come. They are aimed at different application types, after all.....

Comment: I see, I'll be removing the information then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JavaFX is still young and most of its documentation are still using Netbeans IDE, are there documentation for Eclipse IDE [maybe from Helios to present]?

Not officially, but this plugin here http://efxclipse.org provides a lot of cool features and examples that will ease the process of programming with JavaFX 2 on eclipse (At least in 3.X it's great). As of the rest (mainly deploying it) the *no pain, no gain* way of thinking wins.

> My question, if I am to migrate to JavaFX, would I still follow the same routine of creating Forms as I did in Swing?

**No**

You really could by the way stick with swing, but JavaFX and it's new tools will really convince you not to. Since you are speaking of MVC you will be delighted to see how the FXML feature clearly separates the view from the controller and makes a lot simple to create User Interfaces. And if still you don't like the FXML language, you can use [Scene Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/overview/jsbpub-overview.htm) or even create your own view class programmatically (i.e. using Java).

Anyhow, programming user interfaces in JavaFX 2 is a lot easier than java and the result is more beautiful too.